# Nested Loop In An Ansible Jinja Template

Tags: loops, yaml, ansible, jinja2

I'm using ansible to build some swatch conf files, trying to make it as flexible as possible to allow for different actions. I'm stuck on a nested loop in the .j2 file. I have the Ansible vars like so:

```
swatch_files:
  - name: 'syslog'
    tail: '/var/log/syslog'
    watchfor:
      -
        string: 'Stupid FIrst String'
        actions:
          -
            action: "1/2 Slack blah blah action"
            threshold: "Threshold For This first Action"
        actions:
          -
            action: "2/2 Slack blah blah action"
            threshold: "Threshold For This second Action"
      -
        string: 'Crappy Second String'
        actions:
          -
            action: "1/2 Slack blah blah action"
            threshold: "Threshold For This 1 Action"
        actions:
          -
            action: "2/2 Slack blah blah action"
            threshold: "Threshold For This 2 Action"
```

The task does indeed create the file:

```
- name: Swatch | Create the Monit swatch conf files   template:
    src="swatch.monit.j2"
    dest="/etc/monit/conf.d/{{ item.name }}.conf"
    owner=root
    group=root
    mode=0700   with_items: swatch_files   tags:
    - monit
```

And my swatch.conf.j2 file looks like this:

```
{% for watchfor in item.watchfor recursive %}
   watchfor /{{ watchfor.string }}/
{% for actions in watchfor.actions %}
        Action: {{ actions.action }}
        Threshold: {{ actions.threshold }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %
```

But my /etc/swatch/syslog.conf ends up like this:

```
   watchfor /Stupid FIrst String/
    Action: 2/2 Slack blah blah action
    Threshold: Threshold For This second Action

   watchfor /Crappy Second String/
    Action: 2/2 Slack blah blah action
    Threshold: Threshold For This 2 Action
```

It goes through the {% for watchfor in item.watchfor recursive %} loop fine, but then I have the     {% for actions in watchfor.actions %} wrong somehow. It ends up only writing the second action and threshold. I assume it overwrites the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a pure YAML problem. You are overriding the key `actions` in your dict:

```
watchfor:
  -
    string: 'Stupid FIrst String'
    actions:
      -
        action: "1/2 Slack blah blah action"
        threshold: "Threshold For This first Action"
    actions:
      -
        action: "2/2 Slack blah blah action"
        threshold: "Threshold For This second Action"
```

If your `actions` list should have multiple items it should look like this:

```
watchfor:
  - string: 'Stupid FIrst String'
    actions:
      - action: "1/2 Slack blah blah action"
        threshold: "Threshold For This first Action"
      - action: "2/2 Slack blah blah action"
        threshold: "Threshold For This second Action"
```

Comment: Thanks, @udondan, that was indeed my problem.